# Merging spreadsheets?

Tags: scripting, libreoffice

I have a list of **LibreOffice spreadsheets** (xls files) each one **has one sheet**. I wanted to merge all those spreadsheets in one big spreadsheet including all the tabs/sheets inside it. For example:
lets say I have **three xls** files each one has one sheet, in every sheet I have two columns.
I wanted to **combine**  those three xls files in one big spreadsheet so the output of this process is one big spreadsheet contains three sheets with two columns each.

Comment: As far as I know, CSV is a simple format which doesn't know the concept of sheets. Every csv can handle only one table. Other spreadsheet formats can be binary or gzipped XML. Please be more specific about your case.

Comment: How can every CSV file handle only one table? What do you mean by that?

Comment: 1 CSV file = 1 sheet. If your files contain more, then one sheet per file, you probably have some other format. CSV has a simple ASCII architecture, it can be concatenated with `cat`, but you won't have multiple sheets.

Comment: My files are CSV files every CSV file has many sheets.

Comment: Your files are not CSV files if they have multiple sheets, CSV is a pure text format. I am closing this as unclear since pure text files can't have multiple "sheets". If these are somehow actual CSV files, please [edit] your question and add an example and also show what you want them to become. Screenshots of windows programs are not very helpful.

Comment: edited I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Umm, not really :). You're showing us screenshots of the title bar or whatever of windows software. We can't do anything from that. What we need to see is an example of your _data_. Don't post an image of it, CSV is pure text, just run `cat file.csv | head` and paste the output into your question. Then, explain what you mean by "merging". Do you want to remove duplicates? Combine different lines into one? The easiest way to explain is to _show us your desired output_.

Comment: OK, that's better. However, there is no way to get sheets in csv files. The best you can get is three different files. Otherwise, use a spreadsheet program and its format (.odf, .xls or similar).

Comment: how can i do that for a list of xls files?

Comment: @MJA I have no idea, Excel is a Windows program. Why don't you ask on [su] instead?

Comment: My files are designed using Liber Office (in Linux) which can help to save the files as xls extension?

Comment: I reopened this but I still think you would get better answers on [su]. At least, [edit] and explain what "consolidate" means. Show us an example of what you have _and of what you want to have_.

Answer (score 2):

*.xls* is a binary file format. If you're able to `cat`  these files then they're likely not in fact `.xls` files in format, but only in name.

I suspect your `.xls` files are simply CSV files that have the extension `.xls` in their names only. You can confirm the format of a file using the `file` command.

```
$ file test.xls
test.xls: Composite Document File V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, Version 4.0, Code page: 932, Author: kawait, Last Saved By: kawait, Name of Creating Application: Microsoft Excel, Create Time/Date: Wed Dec 20 10:43:55 2000, Security: 0
```

Now the CSV format is really just a text file format, and does not allow for sheets which are allowed in the binary format XLS or ODS (LibreOffice's spreadsheet file format).

So I would suggest simply creating a new file in LibreOffice's Calc program, add sheets to it manually, and then merge the CSV data into each sheet. Calc has the ability to import data from CSV files so you can use this wizard to make this easier.